# /etc/pam.d/ rules for ssh and login

Tags: login, sshd, pam, selinux

In `/etc/pam.d/`, the configuration files for `sshd` and `login` have some rules for `selinux`. Can I simply disable those lines, when I am not using selinux ? I would like to simplify the pam rules.

Specifically, those lines are:

```
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
```

I am asking to be sure, because I think sometimes naively commenting lines out can interfere with tte flow through the rules.

full `sshd` config is bellow:

```
# PAM configuration for the Secure Shell service

# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth

# Standard Un*x authorization.
@include common-account

# SELinux needs to be the first session rule.  This ensures that any lingering context has been cleared.
# Without this it is possible that a module could execute code in the wrong domain.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close

# Set the loginuid process attribute.
session    required     pam_loginuid.so

# Create a new session keyring.
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke

# Standard Un*x session setup and teardown.
@include common-session

# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required     pam_limits.so

# Read environment variables from /etc/environment and
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
# In Debian 4.0 (etch), locale-related environment variables were moved to
# /etc/default/locale, so read that as well.
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process starts
# in the proper default security context.  Only sessions which are intended
# to run in the user's context should be run after this.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open

# Standard Un*x password updating.
@include common-password
```

Comment: "_I think sometimes naively commenting lines out can interfere with tte flow through the rules_". Indeed, sometimes this can be true. PAM rules can include skip logic that requires that the number of rules to be skipped must be stated.

Comment: @roaima - is this the case here ?

Comment: TBH I haven't actually looked. I know the situation can exist because it's hit me in the past, but I would have to review each of the modules and their arguments. I'm not familiar enough with the details of PAM for that to be a quick process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pam_selinux.so`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-pam_selinux/) sets SELinux security contexts for PAM session. If SELinux is *disabled*, the PAM module will not have any effect and can be removed.

Note that if SELinux is in *permissive* mode SELinux rules are still used but not enforced. Removing `pam_selinux.so` will cause processes to run in incorrect security contexts, which likely generates a lot of AVC denial messages in audit log.

If SELinux is enabled later, `pam_selinux.so` needs to be in PAM configuration for user logins to work correctly.

Comment: I understand the pam rules do no harm, when selinux is not being used. but as I said in my original post, I am trying to simplify my pam rules. Can I simply delete those lines referring to selinux. I don't waant this in my config

Comment: I think so. To be certain you should also verify the contents of included files and test the changes (before logging out).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a lot of things you can simplify in the configurations files before trying to remove 2 lines in pam config if you don't know exactly what this means.
It's my 2 cents because I know nothing about pam.